# Slim PHP and GET Parameters

Tags: php, rest, slim

I'm using Slim PHP as a framework for a RESTful API.

How do I grab GET params from the URL in Slim PHP?

For example, if I wanted to use the following:

```
http://api.example.com/dataset/schools?zip=99999&radius=5
```

Comment: These are not GET params?? Are you sure?

Comment: Blerg! I did mean GET, not POST, sorry.

Comment: How about the $_GET variable? Doesn't works?

Comment: Just use `$_GET['zip']` or `$_GET['radius']`

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can do this very easily within the Slim framework, you can use:

```
$paramValue = $app->request()->params('paramName');
```

$app here is a Slim instance.

Or if you want to be more specific

//GET parameter

```
$paramValue = $app->request()->get('paramName');
```

//POST parameter

```
$paramValue = $app->request()->post('paramName');
```

You would use it like so in a specific route

```
$app->get('/route',  function () use ($app) {
          $paramValue = $app->request()->params('paramName');
});
```

You can read the documentation on the request object
http://docs.slimframework.com/request/variables/

As of [Slim v3](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/#how-does-it-work):

```
$app->get('/route', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $paramValue = $request->params(''); // equal to $_REQUEST
    $paramValue = $request->post(''); // equal to $_POST
    $paramValue = $request->get(''); // equal to $_GET

    // ...

    return $response;
});
```

Answer (score 35):

For **Slim 3/4** you need to use the method `getQueryParams()` on the PSR 7 `Request` object.

Citing [Slim 3](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/request.html#the-request-uri) / [Slim 4](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/objects/request.html#the-request-uri) documentation:

> You can get the query parameters as an associative array on the
> Request object using getQueryParams().

Comment: Somehow I'm getting `getQueryParam()` method not found but `getQueryParams()` works fine.

Comment: e.g. `$zip = $request->getQueryParams()['zip'] ?? null;`

Answer (score 4):

I fixed my api to receive a json body OR url parameter like this.

```
$data = json_decode($request->getBody()) ?: $request->params();
```

This might not suit everyone but it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Slim 3

```
$request->getQueryParam('page')
```

or

```
$app->request->getQueryParam('page')
```

Answer (score 2):

**IF YOU WANT TO GET PARAMS WITH PARAM NAME**

```
$value = $app->request->params('key');
```

*The params() method will first search PUT variables, then POST variables, then GET variables. If no variables are found, null is returned. If you only want to search for a specific type of variable, you can use these methods instead:*

*//--- GET variable*

```
$paramValue = $app->request->get('paramName');
```

*//--- POST variable*

```
$paramValue = $app->request->post('paramName');
```

*//--- PUT variable*

```
$paramValue = $app->request->put('paramName');
```

**IF YOU WANT TO GET ALL PARAMETERS FROM REQUEST WITHOUT SPECIFYING PARAM NAME,
YOU CAN GET ALL OF THEM INTO ARRAY IN FORMAT KEY => VALUE**

```
$data = json_decode( $app->request->getBody() ) ?: $app->request->params();
```

$data will be an array that contains all fields from request  as below

```
$data = array(
    'key' => 'value',
    'key' => 'value',
    //...
);
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 2):

Use `$id = $request->getAttribute('id'); //where id is the name of the param`

Answer (score 2):

In Slim 3.0 the following also works:

**routes.php**

```
require_once 'user.php';

$app->get('/user/create', '\UserController:create');
```

**user.php**

```
class UserController
{
    public function create($request, $response, array $args)
    {
        $username = $request->getParam('username'));
        $password = $request->getParam('password'));
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: `getParam()` - method not found

Comment: which version of Slim are you using?
See Slim v3.0 related documentation here:
http://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/request.html

Comment: I would recommend to use POST method for creation of new entries: `$app->post('/users'), '\UserController:create');`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure much about Slim PHP, but if you want to access the parameters from a URL then you should use the:

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

You'll find a bunch of blog posts on Google to solve this.  You can also use the PHP function [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

Comment: George P and fire are right, I just had to use $_GET['var']. I thought maybe because of SlimPHP's built-in routing I'd have to do something fancy, but nope. Good old fashioned $_GET[] works just fine. Just overthinking it - thanks guys!

Comment: I would recommend sticking to $app->request->get('paramName'); even tho this does work.

Comment: @Alex can you explain why you would recommend that?

Comment: @Holonaut This is how the framework expects the parameters to be consumed. Consider in the future, a new middleware is added to escape, encode or trim white space. Your app using `$_SERVER['param']` would not get the benefit, where as, `$app->request()->get('paramName');` would

Answer (score 1):

Inside your api controller function write the following code of line:

```
public function your_api_function_name(Request $request, Response $response)
    {
        $data = $request->getQueryParams();
        $zip = $data['zip'];
        $radius = $data['radius'];

    }
```

The variable $data contains all the query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Probably obvious to most, but just in case, building on vip's answer concerning **Slim 3**, you can use something like the following to get the values for the parameters.

```
        $logger = $this->getService('logger');
        $params = $request->getQueryParams();
        if ($params)  {
            foreach ($params as $key => $param)     {
                if (is_array($param))   {
                    foreach ($param as $value)  {
                        $logger->info("param[" . $key . "] = " . $value);
                    }
                }
                else    {
                    $logger->info("param[" . $key . "] = " . $param);
                }
            }
        }
```